# How to get a range of values as input in R?

Tags: r, function, variables, input

I know that `readline()` is used to get user input. But how to use it to get a range of values?

Eg: I need to get 10 random numbers from user and want to do some operations on them. Please help!

PS: I am totally new to R.

Comment: This is not a duplicate question. I want to input multiple values in a same variable. The other question was different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`scan()` lets you enter multiple inputs, separated by a space or a newline and termined by two newlines.

Assigning the result `x <- scan()` yields a vector in case of multiple inputs.

This does not ensure that you get exactly ten inputs though.

If you want exactly ten inputs, you could prompt ten times:

```
x <- numeric(10)
for(i in 1:10){
  x[i] <- readLines()
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Scan was the function i was looking for. I have doubt. Why do you use <- for variable assignment when = works fine? Wish to understand. Isn't "=" always easier?

Comment: Both work, but `=` is ambiguous. It can mean different things in different contexts, while `<-` can only mean one thing. So when reading it is directly obvious what is meant. See https://google.github.io/styleguide/Rguide.xml